# Assign method locals to class attributes

Tags: python, debugging, python-decorators

When debugging, I sometimes find it useful to access the values of local variables within a class method without necessarily invoking `pdb.set_trace()`.

```
class Calculator:

    # ...

    def add_and_format(x, y):
        sum = x + y
        return '{:.2f}'.format(sum)
```

If I want to access `sum` following a call to `add_and_format`, I could edit the code to be `self.sum = x + y` and inspect it that way. In the case of many local variables, however, it would be simpler if I could use a `@debug` decorator around the method or some `debug_function()` class method to persist all locals variables as attributes. I guess I have in mind something basically equivalent to

```
def my_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # ... method code
    for k, v in locals().items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
    return result
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187022/5712749), which is a good partial solution but I'm unsure how to get it to work for this use case.

Comment: A decorator can't access the decorated function's local variables. They're local after all.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense (in what I linked, the solution is to hijack the function's `return` call, best I can tell). I suppose I'm not married to a decorator implementation -- something like `my_instance.debug()` would also be fine. I'll edit the answer accordingly.