# How do I pass variables across functions?

Tags: python, function, scope, return

I want to pass values (as variables) between different functions.

For example, I assign values to a list in one function, then I want to use that list in another function:

```
list = []

def defineAList():
    list = ['1','2','3']
    print "For checking purposes: in defineAList, list is",list
    return list

def useTheList(list):
    print "For checking purposes: in useTheList, list is",list

def main():
    defineAList()
    useTheList(list)

main()
```

I would expect this to do as follows:

1. Initialize 'list' as an empty list; call main (this, at least, I know I've got right...)
2. Within defineAList(), assign certain values into the list; then pass the new list back into main()
3. Within main(), call useTheList(list)
4. Since 'list' is included in the parameters of the useTheList function, I would expect that useTheList would now use the list as defined by defineAList(), NOT the empty list defined before calling main.

However, my output is:

```
For checking purposes: in defineAList, list is ['1', '2', '3']
For checking purposes: in useTheList, list is []
```

"return" does not do what I expected. What does it actually do? How do I take the list from defineAList() and use it within useTheList()?

I don't want to use global variables.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is what is actually happening:

```
global_list = []

def defineAList():
    local_list = ['1','2','3']
    print "For checking purposes: in defineAList, list is", local_list 
    return local_list 

def useTheList(passed_list):
    print "For checking purposes: in useTheList, list is", passed_list

def main():
    # returned list is ignored
    returned_list = defineAList()   

    # passed_list inside useTheList is set to global_list
    useTheList(global_list) 

main()
```

This is what you want:

```
def defineAList():
    local_list = ['1','2','3']
    print "For checking purposes: in defineAList, list is", local_list 
    return local_list 

def useTheList(passed_list):
    print "For checking purposes: in useTheList, list is", passed_list

def main():
    # returned list is ignored
    returned_list = defineAList()   

    # passed_list inside useTheList is set to what is returned from defineAList
    useTheList(returned_list) 

main()
```

You can even skip the temporary `returned_list` and pass the returned value directly to `useTheList`:

```
def main():
    # passed_list inside useTheList is set to what is returned from defineAList
    useTheList(defineAList())
```

Answer (score 13):

You're just missing one critical step.  You have to explicitly pass the return value in to the second function.

```
def main():
    l = defineAList()
    useTheList(l)
```

Alternatively:

```
def main():
    useTheList(defineAList())
```

Or (though you shouldn't do this! It might seem nice at first, but globals just cause you grief in the long run.):

```
l = []

def defineAList():
    global l
    l.extend(['1','2','3'])

def main():
    global l
    defineAList()
    useTheList(l)
```

The function returns a value, but it doesn't create the symbol in any sort of global namespace as your code assumes.  You have to actually capture the return value in the calling scope and then use it for subsequent operations.

Comment: Thank you- I appreciate that you provided not only an example, but an explanation of why it works that way.

Answer (score 4):

`return` returns a value.  It doesn't matter what name you gave to that value.  Returning it just "passes it out" so that something else can use it.  If you want to use it, you have to grab it from outside:

```
lst = defineAList()
useTheList(lst)
```

Returning `list` from inside `defineAList` doesn't mean "make it so the whole rest of the program can use that variable".  It means "pass the value of this variable out and give the rest of the program one chance to grab it and use it".  You need to assign that value to something outside the function in order to make use of it.  Also, because of this, there is no need to define your list ahead of time with `list = []`.  Inside `defineAList`, you create a new list and return it; this list has no relationship to the one you defined with `list = []` at the beginning.

Incidentally, I changed your variable name from `list` to `lst`.  It's not a good idea to use `list` as a variable name because that is already the name of a built-in Python type.  If you make your own variable called `list`, you won't be able to access the builtin one anymore.

Comment: " It means "pass this variable out and give the rest of the program one chance to grab it and use it"." No; it means "pass this **value** out". There needn't be a variable at all. That's the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your return is useless if you don't assign it

```
list=defineAList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up the concept of a name space. When you assign a variable in a function, you only assign it in the namespace of this function.
But clearly you want to use it between all functions.

```
def defineAList():
    #list = ['1','2','3'] this creates a new list, named list in the current namespace.
    #same name, different list!

    list.extend['1', '2', '3', '4'] #this uses a method of the existing list, which is in an outer namespace
    print "For checking purposes: in defineAList, list is",list
    return list
```

Alternatively, you can pass it around:

```
def main():
    new_list = defineAList()
    useTheList(new_list)
```

Comment: The more relevant concept is *scope*, not namespaces. In Python, a "namespace" is represented by the attributes of an object or the keys of a dictionary. This includes the `globals()` and `locals()` dictionaries, but it also includes, for example, the contents of a module or package.

Answer (score 1):

passing variable from one function as argument to other functions can be done like this

define functions like this

```
def function1():
    global a
    a=input("Enter any number\t")
 
def function2(argument):
    print ("this is the entered number - ",argument)
```

call the functions like this

```
function1()
function2(a)
```

Comment: Indentation is quite off, that should be fixed first. Secondly, since you are specifying `global a`, there is no need for a `return` statement in `function1()`. It is explicitly bad taste to use `global` variables in general, but completely unwarranted in such a simple application. Cf. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).

Comment: @N.Wouda how can i perform such operation without using global?

Comment: `def function1(): return input("Enter any number\t")`. Then, `a = function1()` and `function2(a)`. Of course, you should apply proper formatting of this code, but that's impossible for me to achieve in a comment.

Comment: i must say this just saved me from an app i was developing.the app requires auto creation of session file once a user is logged in and also deletes the file once the user is logged out. i was searching for solution to the logout issue until i stumbled upon this making local variable global and it actually helped and saved me today.Thannks for this.

Comment: @OlowuAbayomi Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try do the following:

```
def funa():
    name=("Bob")
    age=("42")
    return name, age

def funb():
    name, age=funa()
    print(name)
    print(age)

funb()
```

Happens that you gotta call it via `funa()` instead of `age`.

Answer (score 0):

Just return it.

Example:

```
def initiate_excel_corvert():
 
    df = pd.ExcelFile('empty_book.xlsx').parse('Sheet')
    x=[]
    x.append(df['Numbers'])
    x.clear()
    x.extend(df['Numbers'])
    print(len(x))
    print('\n')
    len_of_column_0 =+1 + len(x)
    print("+ add-on ::")
    print(len_of_column_0)
    print('\n')
    
    return render_template('index.html'), insert_into_excel(len_of_column_0)
    
def insert_into_excel(len_of_column_0):
    print ("len_of_column_0 = ", len_of_column_0)
    print('\n')
```