# Error working with defining and receiving values

Tags: python

Hello here is my code:

```
def main():
    #Define Variables
    HomesSold = [0]
    Amount = 0
    HomePrice = [0]
    Amount = GetAmount(Amount)
    HomesSold = AmountHomesSold(Amount)
    #print(HomesSold)


def GetAmount (Amount):
    global amount
    ConvertAmount = float()
    ErrorFlag = False
    Amount = input("Enter the amount of homes sold this year:")
    while not Amount.isdigit():
        Amount = input("Please try again, make sure you are entering a positive number (No commas needed): ")

    print("The amount of houses sold were: ",Amount)
    ConvertAmount = float(Amount)
    return ConvertAmount

def AmountHomesSold(HomePrice):
    HomePrice = 0
    index = 0
    while (index < Amount):
        HomePrice = GetHomePrice()
        HomesSold[index] = HomePrice
        index = index + 1
        print(HomePrice)

    return HomePrice

def GetHomePrice():
    HomePrice = input("How much did the homes sell for?")
    while not HomePrice.isdigit():
        HomePrice = input("Please try again, make sure you are entering a positive number (No commas needed): ")


    return HomePrice

main()
```

So when I try to set my while statement for index < amount, I keep getting an error saying amount is not defined when it is earlier on in my code. Is there a way I can receive that number?

Comment: scope... you need to pass it in as variable to the function.  or make a class and use a class variable.  or use a global variable (this is not the best option).  the variable is not defined in the scope of that function.  it is defined in main and in your GetAmount function.

Comment: How would I receive the return of another function to a separate function without repeating that entire function again

Comment: in main... `HomesSold = AmountHomesSold(Amount)` and where your function is defined... `def AmountHomeSold(Amount)`... [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16043933/623952)

Comment: I recommend you to read the entire official python tutorial before trying to program anything by yourself, it's a nice introduction to programming in general, just skip part you dont understand yet, and then reread it later

Comment: gloomy.penguin solved my problem. Now I have a new issue that I will have to figure out

Comment: Once your question has been answered please don't change it into another question. If you have further questions work on it for a bit and then ask another separate question later.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare "Amount" as a global variable in "AmountHomesSold()" in order to use its value. Otherwise, it will look for a local variable named "Amount" in "AmountHomesSold()" (and there isn't one defined in that function).

Note: I added "global Amount" on the second line to allow the function to use "Amount" as a global variable.

```
def AmountHomesSold():
    global Amount
    HomePrice = 0
    index = 0
    while (index < Amount):
        HomePrice = GetHomePrice()
        HomesSold[index] = HomePrice
        index = index + 1
        print(HomePrice)

        return HomePrice
```

For more information, see [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python).

Comment: better to tell him to not use global variable

Comment: @LudovicViaud It's the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: yes it works, but global variable should be avoided when possible, it's a bad practice, particularly the ones that changes during the execution of differents fonctions. And you dont need the global statement for 'read' a global, just for write it