# Flask/Python - passing variables between functions

Tags: python, function, variables

I've spent a few days looking at this on and off but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried to follow this:

[Passing Variables between functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043797/python-passing-variables-between-functions)

I'm still not clear on what I need to do though.

This is what I have presently but I've tried various permutations:

```
def root():
        hivelogin()
        occupancy()
        print (hiveSessionId)
        return ("Done")
```

I need this to work in lots of places but I'll use hivelogin() as the example:

```
def hivelogin():
        import requests
        url = "https://api.prod.bgchprod.info:443/omnia/auth/sessions"
        payload = "{\n    \"sessions\": [{\n        \"username\": \"xxxxxxxxxxx\",\n        \"password\": \"xxxxxxxxxxx\",\n        \"caller\": \"WEB\"\n    }]\n}"
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/vnd.alertme.zoo-6.1+json",
            'Accept': "application/vnd.alertme.zoo-6.1+json",
            'X-Omnia-Client': "Hive Web Dashboard",
            'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
            }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        data=response.json()
        hiveSessionId = (data['sessions'][0]['sessionId'])
        session['hiveSessionId'] = (data['sessions'][0]['sessionId'])
        return hiveSessionId
```

I've got round it by using a session variable in this case but I don't want to have to do this when I've probably got loads of variables I need to pass around.

So, what I need is for hiveSessionId to my root (or any other) function.

If I do:

```
def root(hiveSessionId=None)
```

I get nothing - as I'd expect.

If I do:

```
def root(hiveSessionId=hiveSessionId)
```

I get an error - as I'd expect.

So, the simple question is how I pass a variable from the function that creates it to any other function in my app - probably between routes as I'm using Flask but I'm using MySQL to give some persistence.

I've done a tiny bit of coding in the past with PHP but please bear in mind that I'm old, been learning Python for about 3 weeks, and this is my first app.  I did the "Hello world" thing, watched a video about Python on Youtube and then did this so it's probably going to make you want to cry.

EDIT: Simplified pseudo version of what I want:

```
def a():
    b()
    return x

def b():
    x=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated version of your pseudo code. Which is getting generated value in function a from another function b.

```
def a():
    x = b()
    return x

def b():
    x=10
    return x
```

Comment: Boom!  Apart from my missing : which I've now fixed, that works exactly as I hoped.  Now to take that and apply it to my real life script.  Thank you very much for that.  I have no idea why I couldn't get to that on my own but it's early days for me.

Comment: Sorry, only just realised how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are a little unaware of the fundamental order of things.
I did not understand a bit where here is the Flask, but if you want to use a variable X in function A, which you calculate in function B, then just return a variable from function like:

```
def A():
    x = 'x value'
    return x

def B(x_as_argument):
    print(x_as_argument)

X = A()
B(X)
```

Or you can use a global variable, but it's not a very good practise. In either case, both options will work with Flask.

Comment: No, I am a LOT unaware of the order of things :)

The above is a snippet from my code.  At the moment, my Flask app is one route to display a dashboard.  That relies on being logged into the Hive API and having a token.  This might be used in lots of functions and routes.

Thank you for your answer.  I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: Ran your script exactly as you have it here and just got: NameError: name 'x' is not defined on line 2.  Tried changing the x to X and vice versa but didn't get anywhere so either your code is wrong or I'm missing some other point.

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously missing something here.  That is just going to output x value.  If I change that to x = 'Hello Andy' then it'll just output Hello Andy. What I'm looking for is x=10 in function B.  Then, function A calls function B first and returns x.  I can't do it with a comment so I'll edit my code.