# Pass Variables Between Functions Returning Templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I use Flask to route URLs to functions, which return templates.
In one of the function I create a list that I would like to use in another function.

I have tried to declare variables in the global scope, and declaring them as global in the function when I modify it, but since I cannot return the list specifically, the changes are not applied in the global scope. I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043797/python-passing-variables-between-functions) but since the function is returning templates instead of modified list, I don't know how to proceed. I know global variables are not ideal, but I am hitting a wall.

Some simplified code:

```
list1 = []

@app.route('/')
def home():
    global list1
    list1 = [1,2,3]
    return render_template('template1.html', list1=list1)

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    list2 = copy(list1)
    return render_template('template2.html', list2=list2)
```

I would want list2 to be [1,2,3].
It currently is [], referencing the unchanged list defined in the global scope before the home() function.

--- EDIT ---
For extra context, I will provide some updated code and more info.
I am trying to make test1.html output [1,2,3].
I tried using the g object, didn't work.

> test.py

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('test_form.html')

@app.route('/test_results', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def form_results():
    g.allPlayers = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        g.allPlayers.append(request.form['player'+str(i)])

    return render_template('test_results.html',allPlayers=g.allPlayers)

@app.route('/test1')
def test1():
    newList = g.allPlayers
    return render_template('test1', newList=newList)
```

> test1.html

```
    <html>
        <header>
            <title>Test</title>
            </script>
        </header>

        <body>
            {{newList}}
            <br>
            <a href="/second">Second<a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> test_form.html

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Template 1</title>
        </script>
    </header>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="test_results">
            <p></p>
            {% for i in range(1,4) %}
                <input type="text" name={{"player" ~ i}}><br>
            {% endfor %}
            &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're not retrieving the list from something more permanent (such as a database) you might want to make a third function where you declare/define your list and then call that function..

```
def my_list():
    make_a_list = [1, 2, 3] # make/get list however you want
    return make_a_list

@app.route('/')
def home():
    list1 = my_list()
    print('list 1 = ', list1) # do stuff with list
    return render_template('template1.html', list1=list1)

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    list2 = my_list()
    print('list 2 = ', list2) # do stuff with list
    return render_template('template2.html', list2=list2)
```

i'm not sure how or where you're getting your list, but this will avoid defining a global.

Comment: A TypeError is thrown, mentioning that test() is missing 1 required positional argument: '_list'

I am at a complete loss here, please expand on this.

Comment: i've edited the original answer for what is hopefully a more useful solution.

Comment: Wow, so simple and effective.

Comment: Well, looks like I spoke too fast. I am getting my list from the fields of a form. I will my original question as I still can't achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session`. So the data will be saved during user session.

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/')
def home():
    session['list1'] = [1,2,3]
    return render_template('template1.html', list1=session['list1'])

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    if session.get('list1'):
        list2 = session['list1']
    else:
        list2 = []
    return render_template('template2.html', list2=list2)
```

Comment: I cannot use `session` as the user will input and change the values during a session.