# Using the same variable in two different functions

Tags: python

I have two functions:

```
def read_temp():
    lines1, lines2 = read_temp_raw()
    while lines1[0].strip()[-3:] != "YES":
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines1, lines2 = read_temp_raw()
    temp1 = calculate_temp(lines1)
    temp2 = calculate_temp(lines2)
    return temp1, temp2

def Temp_difference():
    if temp1 > temp2:
        print(temp1 - temp2)
    else:
        print(temp2 - temp1)
```

I want to use `temp1` and `temp2` in `Temp_difference`. When I try adding the variables globally in `read_temp`, my IDE (Pycharm) says: "Global variable 'temp1/2' is undefined at the module level". I've tried to do it this way:

```
def Temp_difference(temp1, temp2):
    print (abs(temp1-temp2))
```

I'm not getting any warnings or errors here, but I don't know if that is correct. So is there a better/correct way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Passing variables between functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043797/python-passing-variables-between-functions)

Comment: As a side note, there is no really need for the `if/else`. You can just do: `print(abs(temp1 - temp2))`

Comment: I'm not sure @Tomerikoo. Thanks for the side note. I've edited my question.

Comment: To get useful answers please post a [mre]. In this case, we don't see how you call those functions, just their definition so it's hard to help

Comment: I'm not at that point yet. It's part of a project involving temperature sensors with Raspberry Pi. I haven't got a chance to test it yet, but I'm thinking of just `Temp_difference()`. It's about water leak detection.

Comment: When you feel that your functions need variables made by each other, and it is getting tedious to pass around variables, It is a good indication to start using Classes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Temp_difference()` function, you can call your `read_temp()` function. Then you can save the returned values as the `temp1` and `temp2` variables. Here is the code:

```
def Temp_difference():
    temp1, temp2 = read_temp()
    if temp1 > temp2:
        print(temp1 - temp2)
    else:
        print(temp2 - temp1)
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have it, your variables are local to the given functions. You can use a global variable inside other functions by declaring it as `global` within each one of the functions that assigns a value to it:

Comment: There is no real reason to use `global` here. Notice that `read_temp` already returns the values. All that's missing is to pass them to `Temp_difference`

Comment: I agree, however if he's keeping the variable name the same it makes it easier to follow. It also eliminates the need to pass them.

Comment: Global variables are generally frowned upon, because they can affect how a module behaves when it is run.

Comment: *It also eliminates the need to pass them* - but adds the need to make them `global` with all other implications of that. So what is the gain? You can still keep the names exactly the same, because of the reason that they are local...

Comment: When i try to make them `global` Pycharm comes with the message that i described in the question.

Comment: @Techguy Don't make them global. It's *possible*, but not recommended.